# Docker image stopped working after upgrading docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04

I've been using for years a containerized version of a web-application on my development laptop. Usually I do something like

```
docker run -it -d --rm -h app.localhost my-app
```

and, having added `app.localhost` to my `hosts` file, going to `http://app.localhost` everything works. Yesterday an update came for docker and I'm no longer able to do that. Running the image with the same command line options and trying to connect to the application I get a browser error page and checking the logs in the container shows no request at all got to the web server. Running `curl http://app.localhost` in a terminal works fine, and I've been able to fix the problem changing the my command line options to

```
docker run -it -d --rm -p 80:80 -h app.localhost my-app
```

i.e. explicitly exposing port 80.

Can anyone explain what went wrong? And why would `curl` and my web browser behave differently?

**Edit**: to clarify: I'm referring to an update of the docker packages for my OS (Ubuntu 18 if that matters).

Comment: What type of update? Did you chang your Dockerfile/compose file?

Comment: package updates from `apt`, I've added that to the question.

Comment: can you share your Dockerfile, its kind of strange, maybe in ur dockerfile you stopped exposing port.

Comment: So, what do you put into your hosts file? The IP of the container?

Comment: The Dockerfile never changed, and it does not explicitly expose port 80. In the hosts file I've hadded the IP address of the container.

Comment: This is the first time I heard a container could be visit without port specify, without net=host specify...